# Access iframe element and update it to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, iframe

I want to access page2.html element containing img tag and update it to the page1.html img tag or replace img of page1.html to page2.html img.
Both the files are on same domain so no need to worry about cross domain origin policy.

```
// Page1.html

   <body>

   <img id="someimage1" src="./captcha.asp"></img>
   <iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript>
       var getImg = $('iframe').contents().find('#someimage2').html();
       $('#someimage1').replaceWith('<img>' getImg '</img>');
   </script>
   </body>
```

I get DOM Update as [object] [Object]

```
// Page2.html

   <body>

   <img id="someimage2" src="./captcha.asp"></img>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

   </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I will help you with one Vanilla JS solution, you can modify it to JQuery:

First check if your IFrame contains any document at all

**Firefox and Chrome Solution**

```
var frame  = document.getElementById("frame");
if(frame.contentDocument) {
 // get the inner Document
 var innerDocument = frame.contentDocument;
 var img = innerDocument.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
}
```

**IE Solution**

```
var frame  = document.getElementById("frame");
if(frame.contentDocument) {
 // get the inner Document
 var innerDocument = frame.contentWindow.document;
 var img = innerDocument.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
}
```

When you got the image the rest is just a DOM manipulation operations.

**Get Inner Document Body**

```
var getIFrameCOntent = function(iFrame) {
  var frame = document.querySelector(iFrame);
  var innerDocument = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;

   var body = innerDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];  

  return body;
}
```

**Simple Solution**

```
var frame = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.body;
    console.log(frame.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]);
```

Comment: contentDocument property doesn't exist in querySelector prototype. Need to hack around: 
[].forEach.call(document.querySelector(iFrame), function (frame){
 var body = innerDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];  
});

Answer (score 0):

try this code....

```
page1.html...
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imgAA">
    </div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100px;" id="imgBB"/>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#imgAA").load("page2.html",function(data){
                    $("#imgBB").attr("src",$("#imgAA").find("img").attr("src"));
                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

```
page2.html...
<body>
   <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:50px;" id="img2"></img>
</body>
```

try this and tell me it is work fine....

Comment: if you don't want to display page2.html content so hidden the div tag

Comment: vote up and marked as answer if you got which you want to found